# How to know an apoc procedure output name

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j, cypher

I am using some of the awesome `apoc.refactor` procedures. I noticed that in the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring) there is no mention of the output variables names that one can use with `YIELDS`.

I figured out that `refactor.mergeNodes` outputs `node` (as the new merged node), but I can't figure out what is the output name of `refactor.to` or `refactor.from`. I tried `rel` and `newRel` with no success. I am not a java programmer, but inspecting the code (especially [RelationshipRefactorResult.java](http://neo4j-apoc-procedures/src/main/java/apoc/refactor/RelationshipRefactorResult.java)) I thought 'rel' was the one to go.

This is the query I am trying:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->(), (n)
WHERE id(r) = 16 AND id(n) = 4
CALL apoc.refactor.from(r,n) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

And this is the output message:

```
Unknown procedure output: `rel` (line 3, column 36 (offset: 96))
"RETURN rel"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry that's a shortcoming of the current docs.

We want to automate / improve that.

You can see the output types if you `CALL dbms.procedures()`

```
CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name, signature
WITH * WHERE name STARTS WITH 'apoc.refactor'
RETURN name, signature
```

The signature is always `name :: TYPE`
e.g. in your case:

`apoc.refactor.to(relationship :: RELATIONSHIP?, newNode :: NODE?) 
:: (input :: INTEGER?, output :: RELATIONSHIP?, error :: STRING?)`

Parameters:

- Name: `relationship`, Type: Relationship
- Name: `newNode`, Type: Node

Output Columns:

- Name: `input`, Type: Integer
- Name: `output`, Type Relationship
- Name: `error`, Type: String

Comment: Thanks Michael. That query is very helpful in displaying the expected Type of arguments and outputs. E.g. I can see that refactor.to outputs a relationship: `apoc.refactor.to(relationship :: RELATIONSHIP?, newNode :: NODE?) :: (input :: INTEGER?, output :: RELATIONSHIP?, error :: STRING?). Still I don't understand I do I know the output relationship name that I can grab with YIELD.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can now use all of them, I simply love the idea of graph refactoring functions, this is simply great!

Comment: Would love your feedback on the graph refactoring functions.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of Michael, here is a little tool.
Just a query that builds tidy documentation for these. :)
Maybe it can be adapted to work for others procedures too.

```
//EXPOSED YIELD PARAMETERS OUTPUT FROM  apoc.periodic...
CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name, signature
WITH * WHERE name STARTS WITH 'apoc.periodic'
RETURN name AS procedure, 'YIELD', 
      tail(
        apoc.text.split( 
          toString(apoc.text.split(signature, '\\)')[1])
        , '[^a-z]+[^a-zA-Z]*[^a-z]')
      ) AS exposed_parameters
```